# Error: $injector:modulerr ASP.Net Core

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to get angular working in my dotnet webapi project. I've installed angular and angular-ui-router through npm and all scripts added to my default.html page with development and stage/production.

To test it, i've written the following:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>hello</h1>
    {{2+2}}
</body>
```

This code doesn't work and gives me the error: Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error. It can't get myApp. I've included the app.js in default.html where myApp is.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
```

I have tried with ui-view and added a .state, but that doesn't work either. the {{2+2}} works though, if i only type ng-app in  tag. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: https://jsfiddle.net/ztn4kc15/

Comment: can you add a fiddle to reproduce the problem ? Are you adding dependencies in your angular.module call ?

Comment: Just removed my respo

Comment: I meant a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ in which I can reproduce the problem to find the cause.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ah i can try, but my code is a very basic example of a start-up with asp.net core :)

Comment: @Gonzalo.-  https://jsfiddle.net/ztn4kc15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your dependency is wrong. You should use

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwnky9h9/3/)

`ui.route` stands for [AngularUI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), but `angular-route` (the one you added in the fiddle) stands for [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Comment: This still doesn't fix it for me. Just says {{2+2}}

Comment: seeing your github repo, make sure to include the scripts in head tag. You're including them in body - probably js code runs before angular-route has been downloaded. Try that and see if it works (using ui.router)

Comment: Doesn't work. It should be so simple, but there must be something that i'm missing.

Comment: consider upvoting as well :P also which solution worked for you ? using ng-route instead of angular ui route ? moving the scripts ? Keep in mind as the answer states, anguluiar ui router and ngrouter are two different routers for angularjs

Comment: I guess both. I edited the dependency and moved + removed some scripts to make it more clean to the top in head